# Is there a way to get the extent of a query and not each individual feature?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using this solution to get the extent of a query.  It brings every feature geometry back to the client where I then calculate the extent of all the individual geometries.  Since these can be polyline and polygon features this is a very expensive process.  Is there a way to form the query so only the extent is returned?

```
    app.filter.on("zoom-to-features", () => {
    console.log("set map extent to include all annotations matching this criteria");
    all(common.GeoUtil
        .getFeatureLayers(app.map)
        .map(l => {
            var query = new EsriQuery();
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = [];
            query.where = where;
            return l.queryFeatures(query);
        })).then(results => {
            var features = <Array<{ features: Array<esri.Graphic> }>><any>results;
            var extents = features.map(result =>
                result.features
                    .map(f => common.GeoUtil.getExtent(f.geometry))
                    .reduce((a, b) => a ? a.union(b) : b, null));

            var extent = extents.reduce((a, b) => a ? b ? a.union(b) : a : b, null);
            extent && app.map.setExtent(extent);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you want to be using graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent()

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.graphicsutils-amd.html#graphicsextent

Edit:
since my original post, it has also become possible both in ArcGIS Online hosted feature services and ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 to query explicitly for the extent of features by setting the new parameter `returnExtentOnly` to `true`

you can see an example in action [here](https://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/Heritage_Trees_Portland/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=true&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&quantizationParameters=&f=html&token=)

Comment: Good point but that still required the geometries to be loaded on the client.

Comment: thanks for the classification.  I don't think you can form an ArcGIS Server query that returns only the extent of the matching features.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the graphicUtils.graphicsExtent(), but set a high maxAllowableOffset in your query. This will tremendously decrease server response time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider either the [queryExtent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryextent) method of FeatureLayer or the [executeForExtent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#executeforextent) method of queryTask.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and expand with a bit more information on how and where to use your suggested solution?